# Laravel - Stripe still showing archived plans

Tags: php, laravel, strip

I used this in my controller:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(config('services.stripe.secret'));
$plans = \Stripe\Plan::all();
```

Here's the foreach on my blade file:

```
@foreach($plans as $plan)
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" name="plan" type="radio" id="radio{{$plan->id}}" value="{{$plan->id}}" checked />
            <label class="form-check-label" for="radio{{$plan->id}}">{{$plan->product->name}} (${{$plan->amount/100}}/{{$plan->interval}})</label>
        </div>
@endforeach
```

**But it's still showing archived products AND prices?? How do I hide archived products & prices?**

Searched around and can't find an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using might fix this

```
$plans = \Stripe\Plan::all(["active" => true]);
```

[Stripe API Reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans/list?lang=php)

Comment: That got rid of archived prices but didn't get rid of archived products :/ I'll investigate more, thank you